# Difference dates sum with Moment.js

Tags: momentjs

how can I add "moment.preciseDiff(bDt ,eDt )" to "moment.preciseDiff(bDt2 ,eDt2)".
for example:

```
var bDt = moment(new Date(data.startDate), "M/DD/YYYY");
var eDt = moment(new Date(data.endDate), "M/DD/YYYY");
var dtDiff = moment.preciseDiff(bDt, eDt);

var bDt2 = moment(new Date(data.startDate2), "M/DD/YYYY");
var eDt2 = moment(new Date(data.endDate2), "M/DD/YYYY");
var dtDiff2 = moment.preciseDiff(bDt2, eDt2);
```

how can i add dtDiff to dtDiff2

Comment: What is the expected output? Could give provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood this correctly. Here is what I would do; Using momentjs  `diff()` to get the difference between the two dates in milliseconds and adding the difference using `add()` by specifying `ms` as the specifier.

```js
const start1 = moment("26-09-2021", "DD-MM-YYYY");
const end1 = moment("29-09-2021", "DD-MM-YYYY");
const diff1 = moment(end1).diff(start1);

const start2 = moment("18-09-2021", "DD-MM-YYYY");
const addedDate = moment(start2).add(diff1, "ms");
console.log(addedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```